# Load specific XML attributes/values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I've been trying for 2 days to understand LINQ to XML in C# but, I'm so messed up 'cause i never saw a tutorial like the other one, i mean they were all different and since I'm a beginner in C#, and i only need C# in the serverside of my game I was wondering how to

1. Access a skill1 type(attribute) where the name(attribute) is "MyChar"
2. Access the description of skill1 where name(att) is "MyChar1"

---

```
<chars>
    <character name="MyChar1">
        <skill1 type="attack" damage="30">
            description of skill1
            <name>Skill name</name>
            <class1 type="The Class Type"></class1>
            <class2 type="The Class Type 2"></class2>
        </skill1>
         //Almost same thing till skill4    
        <skill2>...</skill4>
    <character name="MyChar2">
        <skill1 type="attack" damage="30"></skill1>
        <skill2>....</skill4>
    </character>
</chars>
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a `</character>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
// parse the document (this is your doc but I've made the xml parseable)
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<chars>
        <character name=""MyChar1"">
        <skill1 type=""attack"" damage=""30"">
            description of skill1
            <name>Skill name</name>
            <class1 type=""The Class Type""></class1>
            <class2 type=""The Class Type 2""></class2>
        </skill1>
        </character>
    <character name=""MyChar2"">
        <skill1 type=""attack"" damage=""30""></skill1>
    </character>
</chars>");

// Access a skill1 type(attribute) where the name(attribute) is "MyChar" 
// this is pretty easy with LINQ. We first get all descendant nodes of type "character"
var skillWhereNameIsMyChar1 = doc.Descendants("character")
    // then take the single one with an attribute named "value"
    .Single(ch => ch.Attribute("name") != null && ch.Attribute("name").Value == "MyChar1")
    // and take that element's child element of type skill1 
    .Element("skill1");
// this will print <skill1 ... /skill1>. However, this is an XElement object, not a string
// so you can continue to access inner text, attributes, children etc.
Console.WriteLine(skillWhereNameIsMyChar1);

// 2. Access the description of skill1 where name(att) is "MyChar1"
// this is tricky because the description text is just floating among other tags
// if description were wrapped in <description></description>, this would be simply
// var description = skillWhereNameIsMyChar1.Element("description").Value;
// here's the hacky way I found to get it in the current xml:

// first get the full value (inner text) of the skill node (includes "Skill Name")
var fullValue = skillWhereNameIsMyChar1.Value;
// then get the concatenated full values of all child nodes (= "Skill Name")
var innerValues = string.Join("", skillWhereNameIsMyChar1.Elements().Select(e => e.Value));
// get the description by dropping off the trailing characters that are actually inner values
// by limiting the length to the full length - the length of the non-description characters
var description = fullValue.Substring(0, length: fullValue.Length - innerValues.Length);
Console.WriteLine(description);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, btw will var doc = XDocument.Load(XMLfile) work the same way? and what would be the output of skill1WhereNameIsMyChar1? and could you explain this? `Substring(0, fullValue.Length - innerValues.Length);`

Comment: @IgliKadija: yes, it will

Comment: As I can see it's just simper to make a <description> :P

Comment: Hey dude, what about "Access a skill1 type(attribute) ex. attack

Comment: @IgliKadija: just do `skillWhereNameIsMyChar1.Attribute("type").Value`